# error: couldn't connect to server

Tags: bitcoind

I did a web search before posting, but none of the similar topics shed any light on my problem.

This is the command I'm using to start bitcoind:

```
./bin/32/bitcoind -datadir=/somedir -daemon
```

This is the contents of my bitcoin.conf, which is located in /somedir (of course):

```
server=1
rpcuser=some_user
rpcpassword=some_password
rpcport=8332
rpctimeout=60
```

Here are the results of `netstat --ip -lpan | grep bitcoin`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8332          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24203/bitcoind  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24203/bitcoind
```

Then I attempt to send a commend to the bitcoind using:

```
./bin/32/bitcoind -datadir=/somedir getinfo
```

Result

```
error: couldn't connect to server
```

I'm probably missing something simple and obvious, but what?

Answer (score 4):

This happens usually when your server isn't yet fully loaded, i.e. the executable/binary is started, but is still busy processing (I think loading the wallet and a vital part of the block chain necessary for most basic RPC commands, although I'm not sure). This could take, depending on your wallet size and processing speed, from a few seconds to several minutes in general.

If that doesn't work please comment!

Comment: Just now, I tried waiting approx. 30 minutes after launching the server. Still the same result.

Comment: Okay, well it was worth a try, but just to be sure: you don't happen to have several millions of Bitcoin addresses in your wallet? Also did this happen when you first run it or later?